# New to SPO from SP2013 - How can I hide specific fields from users since i can't seem to find a New, Edit, and Display forms?

Tags: sharepoint-online

first time here and I apologize for taking up your time.  This has been wracking my brain for a couple weeks now.  So in 2013, i could create the New form to show what i wanted users to see on their initial submission, then i'd create the Edit form so more fields would show for the teams who need to go through the process, and the display form so people can see it without modifying anything.

In SPO, i don't see that separation, each time i change one form, the others change as well.  So i started playing with conditional formatting and got a couple fields hidden until specific choices were made in a previous question.

My main question now is, how can I hide the "Admin" fields from the users in the new form, if they request assistance, I don't want them to add or change the request number or have them change the status or even enter a resolution, when those are meant for the Admin folks to assist them. Is there a way to hide those field unless one of the Admins opens the list/item?

I tried looking up current user, or ME, or to add a group, but can't.  In SP 2013 and SP Designer, i'd use XSL code and hide fields accordingly, but this, i thought would be so much easier, instead i feel like its a step backwards and unsure why New, Edit, and display aren't separate anymore.

Any assistance would be appreciated please.
Josh

Comment: Do you want to modify the modern form? Want to display fields in the modern form according to the login users?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially it.  If a regular user logs in to use the list/app I want them to only see the fields, they need to fill out.  Once done, when my team or I open it, we can then change the status and had additional fields which we can fill in, i.e., resolution and closed, which I do not want the user to do on initial submission.  Then the request number field I want my flow to fill out, not the user and make that field display only, rather than be editable at all.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The new method of creating forms is Microsoft Apps (the Microsoft replacement for Infopath & more). I suggest you to look there to find a solution for what you are asking. You can say goodbye to Sharepoint designer since Microsoft has blocked its use on modern sites. Many things you were able to do in 2013 are not possible anymore.